# Android TableLayout content not showing

Tags: java, android, dynamic, tablelayout

I had a dynamically populated list of TextViews working. But now I want to make it into a multi-column TableView. I've got it dynamically creating the rows and adding them to the layout but nothing will display. Can someone point out what I can't see?

Debugger shows the layout containing the rows containing the textviews containing the text. I've tried making things match_parent width and height and still couldn't get anything to show.

Here is code.

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/detailScroll"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/detailLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/almost_black"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/detailTable"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/almost_black"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:stretchColumns="1" >

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/testRow"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/testText"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Testing" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/protocolButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="40sp"
        android:layout_marginRight="40sp"
        android:background="@drawable/protocol_button"
        android:minHeight="40sp"
        android:onClick="getProtocol"
        android:padding="5sp"
        android:text="@string/protocol_button_text" >
    </Button>
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

java

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.detail);
layout = (TableLayout) this.findViewById(R.id.detailTable);
    TableRow tr;

    if (project.ProtocolNumber != null)
    {
        tr = BuildTableRow(res.getString(R.string.protocol_number_header), project.ProtocolNumber);
        layout.addView(tr);
    }
private TextView BuildTextView(String string)
{
    TextView tv = new TextView(this);
    tv.setLayoutParams(lparams);
    tv.setText(Html.fromHtml(string));
    tv.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    tv.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);

    return tv;
}// BuiltTextView

private TableRow BuildTableRow(String left, String right)
{
    TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
    LayoutParams rowParams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    tr.setLayoutParams(rowParams);
    tr.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
    tr.addView(BuildTextView(left));
    tr.addView(BuildTextView(right));
    return tr;
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to get rid of the LayoutParams